# Certain Liquid filters does not perform filter function

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to use the `handleize` filter from liquid in Jekyll, but it seems to pass the text straight through without doing the filtering.

I have a include file (eg, `_include/example.html`) and inside there is

```
{{ 'Test Text' | handleize }}
```

From reading [some documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#handle) I expect the following text to be generated

```
test-text
```

but instead I get

```
Test Text
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing here? I'm using Jekyll 1.4.3 and liquid 2.5.5.

An interesting point is that there doesn't seem to be the `handle` filter when I look in the Liquid API docs, but confusingly the Jekyll docs points to the doc link given above.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call the \`handleize\` Liquid filter from Jekyll plugin?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769572/how-to-call-the-handleize-liquid-filter-from-jekyll-plugin)

Comment: Where are you adding it in liquid? It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling your own version of this filter, [from Jekyll version 2.4.0 onward](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/history/#v2-4-0) you can use [the built-in `slugify` filter](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#options-for-the-slugify-filter), which basically does what `handleize` did.

Answer (score 0):

Handelize isn't implemented in Jekyll. See [this issue here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-help/issues/97) for an explanation (has to do with Jekyll-Liquid vs. Shopify-Liquid).

There are a couple [Jekyll-Plugins](https://github.com/jeffreylouden/jekyll-handleize) you could use to add this functionality in. Or you could use the Downcase and Replace filters to do the job manually as needed:

```
{{ 'Test Text' | downcase | replace: ' ', '-' }}
```